# Couldn't change the border color for each item on main menu

Tags: wordpress, css, menuitem

I have set `CSS` for each button on main menu. I want to change the border color for each item.

I can change the color what ever I want. But I want to pick out some specific color for each button.

**This part of CSS define the border color:**

```
#main-nav .menu-sub-content {
display: none;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 205;
border-top: 12px solid ;/*#F88C00*/
border-top-color: transparent !important; /*I change to transparent*/
background: #fff;/*2d2d2d*/
color:#999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius : 3px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright : 3px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft  : 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius : 3px;

}
```

**First I tried this**

```
border-top-color: transparent !important;
```

**And then I put this CSS for 3rd button**

```
.ucuncu-nav.menu-sub-content{
/*border-top:12px solid;*/
border-top-color:#669900 !important;
}
```

But it didn't changed. How can I change it now?

Comment: Add a border the the anchor instead of the .menu-sub-content. And then use a child selector to give each item it's own color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of your list have id's which you can use when adding separate borders for what you display on hover. Try this code:

```
#menu-item-17:hover .mega-menu-block {
    border-top: 3px solid red !important;
}

#menu-item-7:hover .mega-menu-block {
    border-top: 3px solid green !important;
}
```

etc, for all your `<li>` menu items with different id's. `!important` rule is here a quick solution because the is overridden for some default styles.

Comment: I understand well.Thank you.